# C++ Forms Apps Not updating Text Box

Tags: c++, forms, textbox, updating

I have a simple windows forms application where I am querying a server app running on another computer. The querying works fine, but I am having trouble displaying the results to a textbox. I was testing it in a for loop and it only writes the last result to the text box, even if I use Thread::Sleep for 5 seconds between query. How do I get it to write the results to the textbox each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the refresh() method on the form after each update and it will be displayed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx